# Streaming an Excel file to S3 In-Memory? Why does ByteOutputStream.reset() on a ZipOutputStream cause write not to work?

Tags: java, excel, scala, amazon-s3, apache-poi

I'm currently working with Apache POI to create an excel file. I want to send this file to AWS S3 via [multipart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html). 
I'm using the [SXSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html) combined with the substitution techniques used by the [BigGridDemo](http://web.archive.org/web/20120525160349/http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/BigGridDemo.java.html) in order to create the document itself and send the sheet data. This is where it gets a little tricky. I have something mostly working, but am generating an invalid excel file due to `NUL`s being written into the XML file that composed the sheet data.

In trying to track down *why* this happens I've stumbled onto this:

```
import java.io._
import java.util.zip._
val bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
val zo = new ZipOutputStream(bo)
zo.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("1"))
zo.write("hello".getBytes())
zo.write("\nhello".getBytes())
val bytes1 = bo.toByteArray()
// bytes1: Array[Byte] = Array(80, 75, 3, 4, 20, 0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 107, -121, -9, 76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49)

bo.reset()
zo.write("hello".getBytes())
val bytes2 = bo.toByteArray() // bytes2: Array[Byte] = Array()
zo.flush()
val bytes2 = bo.toByteArray() // bytes2: Array[Byte] = Array()
bo.size //res11: Int = 0
zo.putNextEntry() // If I make a new entry it works but I can't do this in real code...
bo.size // res17: Int = 66
```

It seems that when I reset the underlying byte output stream it causes the ZipOutputStream to note write anything anymore. This surprised me, so I went looking into the [underlying source code of ZipOutputStream](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.java). I noticed the default method is DEFLATED, which just calls [DeflaterOutputStream#write](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.java#L199), I then looked into the deflater code itself thinking that maybe there's something deeper in the compression algorithm that I don't understand that requires the stream to not be reset or that is somehow affected by it. I found a reference to [FULL_FLUSH](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/zip/Deflater.java#L393) and noted

> The compression state is reset so that the inflater that works on the compressed output data can restart from this point if previous compressed data has been damaged or if random access is desired.

Which sounded good to me since I could imagine that a reset byte stream could be seen as damaged data perhaps. So I repeated my minimal experiment:

```
import java.io._
import java.util.zip._
val bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
val zo = new ZipOutputStream(bo)
zo.setLevel(Deflater.FULL_FLUSH)
zo.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("1"))
zo.write("hello".getBytes())

val bytes1 = bo.toByteArray()
// bytes1: Array[Byte] = Array(80, 75, 3, 4, 20, 0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 84, 75, -8, 76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49)

zo.flush()
bo.reset()
zo.write("\nhello".getBytes())
zo.flush()
val bytes2 = bo.toByteArray() // bytes2: Array[Byte] = Array()
```

So no dice. My goal here was to keep everything in memory (hence the byte arrays) and keep the memory pressure low by removing the bytes I had already written to the UploadPartRequest, but this really throws a wrench into things since I'm under the impression that the XML file *must* be compressed since the excel file format is effectively a zip file. My full code is obviously a bit more complicated and is using the [Play framework](https://www.playframework.com) and Scala 2.12.6, [I've put it on github here and added some additional comments if you'd like to look at it or run it.](https://github.com/EdgeCaseBerg/poc-streaming-excel-file-to-s3)

I know I could accomplish uploading this file to s3 in parts by writing the excel file out to disk first and then uploading it, but for my purposes I'm hoping for an all in-memory solution so I don't have to deal with disk space problems on web servers when large temp files are generated. By keeping the rows generated uploaded as they're made I was thinking the memory pressure should stay fairly constant per upload. Here's what the current code generates in the xml file sheet data:

[image]

...

[image]

Which implies to me that despite my experiment showing no bytes, at some point more bytes happen and are written to the file since the NULs end eventually.

So... why does this happen? Why does `ByteArrayOutputStream.reset()` cause a problem for writing on the `ZipOutputStream`? If I don't call .reset() it seems that the `ByteArrayOutputStream` will expand until it's huge and cause Out of Memory errors? Or should I not worry since the data is getting compressed anyway?

Comment: You can have a look at [Benji](https://github.com/zengularity/benji), which support streaming for S3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's the fault of `ByteArrayOutputStream.reset()`.

Similar to `CipherStreams` and other filter streams, `DeflaterOutputStream` and thus `ZipOutputStream` does not *actually* write to the underlying stream (your `ByteArrayOutputStream`) until it can/needs to (sometimes even when you flush).

I believe in this case of a `ZipInputStream` it might only write to the underlying stream on certain block sizes or upon closing of the `ZipEntry`; Not exactly sure but that's my guess.

Example:

```
val bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
val zo = new ZipOutputStream(bo)
zo.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("example entry"))

// v prints the entry header bytes v
println(bo.toString())

zo.write("hello".getBytes())
zo.flush();

// v still only the entry header bytes v
println(bo.toString())
```

One thing I noticed in `ExcelStreamingToS3Service - line 155` you might want to change to `zos.write(byteBuffer, offset, offset + bytesRead)`, or something similar. Writing the full buffer could certainly be what is causing all those `NUL` characters, since your buffer may not have been filled during the read and still have many empty indices. After all, it looks like the the xml continues where it left off from before the `NUL`s like here: `<c r="C1 ... 940" t="inlineStr">` so it does seem like you're writing all the data, just interspersing it with `NUL`s.

Comment: You're totally right about `zos.write`! I change it to `if (bytesRead != -1) {zos.write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead)}` and had no NULs and could open the excel file without any trouble! Also it not writing until it has to makes sense I think, it sounds like it should be influenced by the flush behavior right? Do you still only get the headers if you set it to the more aggresive flushing settings?

Comment: Yes, the certain flush behaviors can influence writing to the underlying stream. For example `DeflaterOutputStream.flush()` will write to the underlying stream when `DeflaterOutputStream.synchFlush` is true. *However* it seems there's no API to actually set the flush behavior for `ZipOutputStream` **and your call to `zo.setLevel(Deflater.FULL_FLUSH)` is incorrect, since `level` is referring to compression level, not flush level.** This type unsafety for `setLevel()` is one reason why enums are far superior to int constants...

Comment: If you still want to set the flush behavior, then you would have to copy-paste and re-implement `ZipOutputStream` and maybe call the superconstructor for `DeflatedOutputStream` passing `true` for the `synchFlush` parameter or add API to pass flush behavior down to the `Deflater` that is being used.  Unfortunately, `DeflatedOutputStream.synchFlush` and the deflate flush behaviors of the `Deflater` are unconnected, so just know that one wont necessarily correspond to the other.

Comment: If this answered your question then please accept. Thanks. :)

Comment: Bah that's what I get for reading too quickly in JavaDoc world. Thanks for pointing that out, it's odd that there is 0 control over the flush level without subclassing, I'll give subclassing a try once I have some more time to see if I can't get the bytes out right away. For educational sake, not going to do that in the real code since it now generates a valid file. Thanks!

Comment: I know, I hate how restrictive some of these APIs are and I hate the old int-flag way of setting options/behaviors. Glad I could help though. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

Check this PDF, Practical Guidelines for Boosting Java Server Performance, from Bell Laboratories: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.3674&rep=rep1&type=pdf

It talks about everything including the used of the reset method.

Also, Take a look into this post: http://java-performance.info/java-io-bytearrayoutputstream/

Finally, you should always have a try/catch for issues such as Out of Memory.

> If I don't call .reset() it seems that the ByteArrayOutputStream will
>   expand until it's huge and cause Out of Memory errors?

Let me know if this helps or not.

Comment: I'm reading that paper of yours and am halfway through it, seems to suggest that using the reset method is good since it will re-use objects as far as performance goes. The blog post suggests using `writeTo` and avoiding the byte array due to synchronization slowdowns. So your answer is interesting/helpful from a performance problem but doesn't answer the question about why the byte array is not getting the results of `zo.write` at all.